# Sharing in RoboVM using the iOS share menu?

Tags: java, ios, share, robovm

How would I go about opening a share menu such as the one found in the iOS photos app as an action for an existing button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the UIAvtivityViewController class. You can share strings and images

```
NSString textShare = new NSString("This is the text to share");
NSArray texttoshare = new NSArray(textShare);
UIActivityViewController share = new UIActivityViewController(texttoshare,null);
presentViewController(share, true, null);
```

Comment: Will that share to anything installed such as Facebook or does using those kinds of apps require a bit more? And of course, thanks for the reply! It really helped!

Comment: what am i calling presentViewController on? i cant call it on 'this'

Comment: UIApplication.getSharedApplication().getKeyWindow().getRootViewController().presentViewController(); is what I use to open 'share'

Comment: In your example, you are sharing the string. How would you share a file, say, an image? (or even an audio file?) Thanks